# Getting 'EMAIL_NOT_FOUND' error when trying to get the token from Firebase

Tags: firebase, postman

I am trying to get the firebase token through postman with email and password by using below API

```
https://identitytoolkit.googleapis.com/v1/accounts:signInWithPassword?key={API_KEY}
```

Below is the body

```
{"email":"{YOUR_EMAIL_ADDRESS}","password":"{PASSWORD}","returnSecureToken":true}
```

I am using proper email and password which I used to log into firebase console. But I am getting EMAIL_NOT_FOUND error as below.

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 400,
    "message": "EMAIL_NOT_FOUND",
    "errors": [
      {
        "message": "EMAIL_NOT_FOUND",
        "domain": "global",
        "reason": "invalid"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

From the firebase document, we will get this error when **"There is no user record corresponding to this identifier. The user may have been deleted."**

But I am able to see the email under "Users and permissions" and the role as 'owner'. I am using the same email ID. Can anyone please help me to fix this issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add the user in the authentication list:

```
https://console.firebase.google.com/project/*****/authentication/users
```

Firebase add user panel:
[image]

Comment: @Scratte Oh! Okay so I saw the original path appear as a link then saw the image link and hence thought it was link only. I apologise. I made a mistake. But now with the edit I see there was no link only